# how the get value of string with ignoring the whitespaces using regex in python

Tags: python, regex

if I have this data

```
/ 260: fcn.004020b0 (int32_t arg_4h, int32_t arg_8h);
|           ; var int32_t var_324h @ ebp-0x324
|           ; arg int32_t arg_4h @ ebp+0x4
|           ; arg int32_t arg_8h @ ebp+0x8
|           0x004020b0      55             push ebp
|           0x004020b1      8bec           mov ebp, esp
|           0x004020b3      81ec24030000   sub esp, 0x324
|           0x004020b9      6a17           push 0x17                   ; 23
|           0x004020bb      ff151c304000   call dword [sym.imp.KERNEL32.dll_IsProcessorFeaturePresent] ; 0x40301c
|           0x004020c1      85c0           test eax, eax
|       ,=< 0x004020c3      7407           je 0x4020cc
|       |   0x004020c5      b902000000     mov ecx, 2
|       |   0x004020ca      cd29           int 0x29
|       |   ; CODE XREF from fcn.004020b0 @ 0x4020c3
|       `-> 0x004020cc      a340744000     mov dword [0x407440], eax   ; [0x407440:4]=0
|           0x004020d1      890d3c744000   mov dword [0x40743c], ecx   ; [0x40743c:4]=0
|           0x004020d7      891538744000   mov dword [0x407438], edx   ; [0x407438:4]=0
```

and i want the get the opcodes

```
55
8bec
81ec24030000
6a17
--snip--
```

till i have the full opcodes

```
558bec81ec240300006a17--snip--
```

How i can do it in python using regex ?
I tried `0x[0-9a-z]\ *(.*?)\ +` but it didn't works

Comment: You should show your python code - preferably a [mcve].

Comment: Your character class `[0-9a-z]` should probably have some number of repetitions.  Otherwise it will only match a single hex digit.  I recommend testing your regex on https://regex101.com/

Comment: Maybe `0x[0-9A-Fa-f]{8} *(\S+)`?

Comment: Or `0x[0-9a-f]+[^\S\n]+([a-f0-9]+)[^\S\n]`

Comment: Hi @0x5453 , I didn't write the python code because I don't know the right regex pattern to use, i used this website regexr.com to get it but I don't know how to write the right pattern

Comment: Why not just do it without regex?

Comment: is there a better way than regex @mkrieger1 ?

Comment: Thank you @WiktorStribiżew and The fourth bird for this

Comment: You could just use the `split` and `startswith` string methods and a few `if` statements.

Comment: What is the criterion to not include the opcode `ff151...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
0x[0-9a-fA-F]{8} *(\S+)
0x[0-9a-fA-F]{8}[\t ]*(\S+)
0x[0-9a-fA-F]{8}[^\S\n]*(\S+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yBQhIZ/2). *Details*:

- `0x` - a literal text
- `[0-9a-fA-F]{8}` - eight hex chars
- `*` - zero or more spaces
- `[\t ]*` - zero or more spaces/tabs
- `[^\S\n]*` - zero or more whitespaces that are not LF (line feed, `"\n"`) chars
- `(\S+)` - Group 1: one or more non-whitespace chars

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/jSfs1H):

```py
import re
text = "/ 260: fcn.004020b0 (int32_t arg_4h, int32_t arg_8h);\n|           ; var int32_t var_324h @ ebp-0x324\n|           ; arg int32_t arg_4h @ ebp+0x4\n|           ; arg int32_t arg_8h @ ebp+0x8\n|           0x004020b0      55             push ebp\n|           0x004020b1      8bec           mov ebp, esp\n|           0x004020b3      81ec24030000   sub esp, 0x324\n|           0x004020b9      6a17           push 0x17                   ; 23\n|           0x004020bb      ff151c304000   call dword [sym.imp.KERNEL32.dll_IsProcessorFeaturePresent] ; 0x40301c\n|           0x004020c1      85c0           test eax, eax\n|       ,=< 0x004020c3      7407           je 0x4020cc\n|       |   0x004020c5      b902000000     mov ecx, 2\n|       |   0x004020ca      cd29           int 0x29\n|       |   ; CODE XREF from fcn.004020b0 @ 0x4020c3\n|       `-> 0x004020cc      a340744000     mov dword [0x407440], eax   ; [0x407440:4]=0\n|           0x004020d1      890d3c744000   mov dword [0x40743c], ecx   ; [0x40743c:4]=0\n|           0x004020d7      891538744000   mov dword [0x407438], edx   ; [0x407438:4]=0"
print(re.findall(r'0x[0-9a-fA-F]{8}[\t ]*(\S+)', text))
# => ['55', '8bec', '81ec24030000', '6a17', 'ff151c304000', '85c0', '7407', 'b902000000', 'cd29', 'a340744000', '890d3c744000', '891538744000']
```