# how to dict values based on address and their code in python

Tags: python, regex

I have this data

```
            ; CALL XREF from fcn.00401c60 @ 0x401c77
/ 43: fcn.00401dd0 (int32_t arg_8h, int32_t arg_ch);
|           ; arg int32_t arg_8h @ ebp+0x8
|           ; arg int32_t arg_ch @ ebp+0xc
|           0x00401dd0      55             push ebp
|           0x00401dd1      8bec           mov ebp, esp
|           0x00401dd3      56             push esi
|           0x00401dd4      8b750c         mov esi, dword [arg_ch]
|           0x00401dd7      57             push edi
|           0x00401dd8      8b7d08         mov edi, dword [arg_8h]
|           0x00401ddb      3bfe           cmp edi, esi
|       ,=< 0x00401ddd      7416           je 0x401df5
|       |   0x00401ddf      90             nop
|       |   ; CODE XREF from fcn.00401dd0 @ 0x401df3
|      .--> 0x00401de0      8b46fc         mov eax, dword [esi - 4]
|      :|   0x00401de3      85c0           test eax, eax
|     ,===< 0x00401de5      7407           je 0x401dee
|     |:|   0x00401de7      6a00           push 0
|     |:|   0x00401de9      ffd0           call eax
|     |:|   0x00401deb      83c404         add esp, 4
|     |:|   ; CODE XREF from fcn.00401dd0 @ 0x401de5
|     `---> 0x00401dee      83ee08         sub esi, 8
|      :|   0x00401df1      3bf7           cmp esi, edi
|      `==< 0x00401df3      75eb           jne 0x401de0
|       |   ; CODE XREF from fcn.00401dd0 @ 0x401ddd
|       `-> 0x00401df5      5f             pop edi
|           0x00401df6      b001           mov al, 1
|           0x00401df8      5e             pop esi
|           0x00401df9      5d             pop ebp
\           0x00401dfa      c3             ret

/ 260: fcn.004020b0 (int32_t arg_4h, int32_t arg_8h);
|           ; var int32_t var_324h @ ebp-0x324
|           ; arg int32_t arg_4h @ ebp+0x4
|           ; arg int32_t arg_8h @ ebp+0x8
|           0x004020b0      55             push ebp
|           0x004020b1      8bec           mov ebp, esp
|           0x004020b3      81ec24030000   sub esp, 0x324
|           0x004020b9      6a17           push 0x17                   ; 23
|           0x004020bb      ff151c304000   call dword [sym.imp.KERNEL32.dll_IsProcessorFeaturePresent] ; 0x40301c
|           0x004020c1      85c0           test eax, eax
|       ,=< 0x004020c3      7407           je 0x4020cc
|       |   0x004020c5      b902000000     mov ecx, 2
|           0x00402178      c78254734000.  mov dword [edx + 0x407354], 2
|           0x00402182      b804000000     mov eax, 4
|           0x00402187      6bc800         imul ecx, eax, 0
|           0x0040218a      8b150c404000   mov edx, dword [0x40400c]   ; [0x40400c:4]=0xbb40e64e
|           0x00402190      89540df8       mov dword [ebp + ecx - 8], edx
|           0x00402194      b804000000     mov eax, 4
|           0x00402199      c1e000         shl eax, 0
|           0x0040219c      8b0d08404000   mov ecx, dword [0x404008]   ; [0x404008:4]=0x44bf19b1
|           0x004021a2      894c05f8       mov dword [ebp + eax - 8], ecx
|           0x004021a6      6850364000     push 0x403650               ; 'P6@' ; "@s@"
|           0x004021ab      e8d0feffff     call fcn.00402080
|           0x004021b0      8be5           mov esp, ebp
|           0x004021b2      5d             pop ebp
\           0x004021b3      c3             ret
```

i want to get the ADDRESS `fcn.ADDRESS` and their opcodes like here in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70715013/how-the-get-value-of-string-with-ignoring-the-whitespaces-using-regex-in-python) and puts it in dict like this

```py
{"00401dd0":"558bec81ec240300006a17ff151c30400085c07407b902000000cd29a340744000890d3c744000891538744000--snip--","004020b0":"558bec81ec240300006a17ff151c30400085c07407b902000000cd29a340--snip--"}
```

and as you can see the end of opcodes starting with `\` character not the `ret` string:

```
\           0x004021b3      c3             ret
```

so is it possable to do it in python using regex or something like that in python ?

Comment: "Is it possible?" are not great ways of asking, please do try to show at least a minimal example of what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By extracting each of the code blocks and combining that output with using the answer to the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70715013/how-the-get-value-of-string-with-ignoring-the-whitespaces-using-regex-in-python).

## Code

[Python Demo](https://ideone.com/RsjoxD)

```
import re
text = """            ; CALL XREF from fcn.00401c60 @ 0x401c77
/ 43: fcn.00401dd0 (int32_t arg_8h, int32_t arg_ch);
|           ; arg int32_t arg_8h @ ebp+0x8
|           ; arg int32_t arg_ch @ ebp+0xc
|           0x00401dd0      55             push ebp
|           0x00401dd1      8bec           mov ebp, esp
|           0x00401dd3      56             push esi
|           0x00401dd4      8b750c         mov esi, dword [arg_ch]
|           0x00401dd7      57             push edi
|           0x00401dd8      8b7d08         mov edi, dword [arg_8h]
|           0x00401ddb      3bfe           cmp edi, esi
|       ,=< 0x00401ddd      7416           je 0x401df5
|       |   0x00401ddf      90             nop
|       |   ; CODE XREF from fcn.00401dd0 @ 0x401df3
|      .--> 0x00401de0      8b46fc         mov eax, dword [esi - 4]
|      :|   0x00401de3      85c0           test eax, eax
|     ,===< 0x00401de5      7407           je 0x401dee
|     |:|   0x00401de7      6a00           push 0
|     |:|   0x00401de9      ffd0           call eax
|     |:|   0x00401deb      83c404         add esp, 4
|     |:|   ; CODE XREF from fcn.00401dd0 @ 0x401de5
|     `---> 0x00401dee      83ee08         sub esi, 8
|      :|   0x00401df1      3bf7           cmp esi, edi
|      `==< 0x00401df3      75eb           jne 0x401de0
|       |   ; CODE XREF from fcn.00401dd0 @ 0x401ddd
|       `-> 0x00401df5      5f             pop edi
|           0x00401df6      b001           mov al, 1
|           0x00401df8      5e             pop esi
|           0x00401df9      5d             pop ebp
\           0x00401dfa      c3             ret

/ 260: fcn.004020b0 (int32_t arg_4h, int32_t arg_8h);
|           ; var int32_t var_324h @ ebp-0x324
|           ; arg int32_t arg_4h @ ebp+0x4
|           ; arg int32_t arg_8h @ ebp+0x8
|           0x004020b0      55             push ebp
|           0x004020b1      8bec           mov ebp, esp
|           0x004020b3      81ec24030000   sub esp, 0x324
|           0x004020b9      6a17           push 0x17                   ; 23
|           0x004020bb      ff151c304000   call dword [sym.imp.KERNEL32.dll_IsProcessorFeaturePresent] ; 0x40301c
|           0x004020c1      85c0           test eax, eax
|       ,=< 0x004020c3      7407           je 0x4020cc
|       |   0x004020c5      b902000000     mov ecx, 2
|           0x00402178      c78254734000.  mov dword [edx + 0x407354], 2
|           0x00402182      b804000000     mov eax, 4
|           0x00402187      6bc800         imul ecx, eax, 0
|           0x0040218a      8b150c404000   mov edx, dword [0x40400c]   ; [0x40400c:4]=0xbb40e64e
|           0x00402190      89540df8       mov dword [ebp + ecx - 8], edx
|           0x00402194      b804000000     mov eax, 4
|           0x00402199      c1e000         shl eax, 0
|           0x0040219c      8b0d08404000   mov ecx, dword [0x404008]   ; [0x404008:4]=0x44bf19b1
|           0x004021a2      894c05f8       mov dword [ebp + eax - 8], ecx
|           0x004021a6      6850364000     push 0x403650               ; 'P6@' ; "@s@"
|           0x004021ab      e8d0feffff     call fcn.00402080
|           0x004021b0      8be5           mov esp, ebp
|           0x004021b2      5d             pop ebp
\           0x004021b3      c3             ret
"""


result = {}
for match in re.finditer(r"/\s*\d+:\s*fcn\.(?P<name>[a-f0-9]+)\s*\((?P<args>[^)]+)\);\s*(?P<analysis>[^\\]+^\\[^\r\n]+)", text, re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE):
    bytecode = ''.join(re.findall(r'0x[0-9a-fA-F]{8}[\t ]*(\S+)', match.group("analysis")))
    result[match.group("name")] = bytecode


print(result)
```

## Output

```
{'00401dd0': '558bec568b750c578b7d083bfe7416908b46fc85c074076a00ffd083c40483ee083bf775eb5fb0015e5dc3', '004020b0': '558bec81ec240300006a17ff151c30400085c07407b902000000c78254734000.b8040000006bc8008b150c40400089540df8b804000000c1e0008b0d08404000894c05f86850364000e8d0feffff8be55dc3'}
```